# Recreate DefaultWebsite on IIS7 / Windows Web Server 2008

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008, webserver

I have accidently deleted the default-website on an "experimental" machine.
It is a standard-installation of "Windows Web Server 2008" with II7 running.

I have already tried to create a custom website on my own, but this always fails when I try to access the website in the browser (remote and locally). There is an endless number of permission- and setting - errors.

Could you please show me a link to a tutorial on what to do in my case?
Or possibly any suggestions what common pitfalls are in such situations?

Thank you!
Daniel Lang

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your site points to %systemdrive%\inetpub\wwwroot, and then it has little difference from the default one.

Learning about how to back up IIS settings on IIS is a must for beginners,

http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2007/03/18/Most-Important-AppCmd-Commands_3A00_-Backing-up-and-restoring-IIS7-configuration.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Save your custom code (virtual directories) and reinstall IIS? Probably cleanest.